# how can I rewrite this program without this statement

Tags: c++

I need to change the outer `if()` statement into an `if () else` statement. Can someone guide me how?

I tried to change the 2nd `if` to `if-else`, but I get an error.
Remember I need to remove the `continue` statement without affecting the results of the program.

```
// This program calculates the charges for DVD rentals.
// Every third DVD is free.
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int dvdCount = 1;   // DVD counter
    int numDVDs;        // Number of DVDs rented
    double total = 0.0; // Accumulator
    char current;       // Current release, Y or

    // Get the number of DVDs.
    cout << "How many DVDs are being rented? ";
    cin >> numDVDs;

    // Determine the charges,
    do
    {
        if ((dvdCount % 3) == 0)
        {
            cout << "DVD #" << dvdCount << " is free!\n";
            continue; // Immediately start the next iteration GET RID OF THIS WITHOUT 
            // HAVING PROBLEMS
        }

        cout << "Is DVD #" << dvdCount;
        cout << " a current release? (Y/N) ";
        cin >> current;

        if (current == 'Y'  || current == 'y')
            total += 3.50;
        else
            total += 2.50;
    } while (dvdCount++ < numDVDs);

    // Display the total
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "The total is $" << total << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could tell use the error you're getting. Looks pretty simple to just wrap the code you're skipping with `continue` in an `else` clause.

Comment: You should do proper formatting. Also if you have a new question, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why when you were asked to change the outer `if`, you instead decided to try and change the second `if`. Here's how it should be done.

```
if ((dvdCount % 3) == 0)
{
    cout << "DVD #" << dvdCount << " is free!\n";
}
else
{
    cout <<"Is DVD #" << dvdCount;
    cout << " a current release? (Y/N) ";
    cin >> current;
    if (current == 'Y' || current == 'y')
        total += 3.50;
    else
        total += 2.50;
}
```

The second `if` already is an `if ... else` maybe that was what was confusing you.

Comment: Thanks!, sorry I didn't write the modified code!